# Azure Git Commit Error: Permission denied fatal - unable to possess path

Tags: asp.net, git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2022

I have Windows Service in ASP.NET Framework-4.8.
I opened it in Visual Studio 2022, and as I wanted to commit to Azure repo as I've been doing, I got this error:

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
error: open(".vs/eApplicationService/FileContentIndex/6e0c3c20-14e0-4ba0-9337-9c4d788783a3.vsidx"): Permission denied
fatal: Unable to process path .vs/eApplicationService/FileContentIndex/6e0c3c20-14e0-4ba0-9337-9c4d788783a3.vsidx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to add `.vs/` to your `.gitignore`. Or select the default ignore file from [gitignore.io](https://gitignore.io/) and add that to the root of your git repo.